# no module named rpm - when i call yum on shell

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, rpm, yum

I installed python 2.7.5 and mod_wsgi on centos machine linux os. And this happened:

```
# yum
Error processing line 1 of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/abrt.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named abrt_exception_handler

Remainder of file ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 22, in <module>
    import yummain
  File "/usr/share/yum/yummain.py", line 22, in <module>
    import clientStuff
  File "/usr/share/yum/clientStuff.py", line 18, in <module>
    import rpm
ImportError: No module named rpm
```

yum module doesn't run because of rpm module doesnt exist. 
I don't know how can I install the python-rpm module and will it work if I install it?

Thanks.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib` sounds wrong. Did you by any chance replace your system's python? That's usually a bad idea.

Comment: Actually, yes, i have changed the active python version. Python 2.6 was installed before and after I install 2.7.5 to /usr/local/lib. And i want to use this version with mod_wsgi so i changed hardlink /usr/bin/python > /usr/local/bin/python or something like  that.

Comment: In addition, I have copied some module directories from /usr/lib/python2.6/lib/site-packages to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.
Now i want to rebuild all python system on linux. How can I remove and reinstall python as python 2.7 ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same..

Comment: We have changed the server machine.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't touch your system's python installation. Updating the sysem's python version should be left to the distirbution.

If you need a newer version then install it, but keep it separate form the system version.

You should restore the original `/usr/bin/python` - it usually is a symlink (in this case to `/usr/bin/python2.6`.

You'll probably want to remove and reinstall python2.7, as copying modules (specially if they contain binary extensions) from one version to another can lead to problems. Install the packages you need directly using the new python version:

```
python2.7 setup.py ...
```

If you want `mod_wsgi` to use the newer version, use the [WSGIPythonHome](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome) directive to point it to the right prefix (`/usr/local`).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, what I did is to manually download the old version python and reinstall it with rpm:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep python- | grep 2.6
$ sudo rpm -ivh --force ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/scientificlinux/6.5/x86_64/updates/fastbugs/python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

After the reinstallation of python, my yum works correctly.