# No module named rpm

Tags: python, linux, centos

I am new in centos I tried to upgrade python version in centos and now yum is breaked in it. below message is showing if yum command runs.

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
   No module named rpm
Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.
It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Mar  8 2015, 07:21:16)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]
If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq**
```

I have run this command `rpm -q rpm-python` then it showing  `rpm-python-4.8.0-38.el6_6.x86_64`

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: (But [this related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490921/no-module-named-rpm-when-i-call-yum-on-shell) may help)